# Origin of the term `quermassintegral'.

Tags: terminology, convex-analysis

What is the origin of the term `quermassintegral'? I think this is a german word. What would be its literal translation in English?

The definition of [quermassintegrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_volume#Quermassintegrals) from wikipedia:

> Let $K\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a convex body, and let
>   $B\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be the unit ball. The mixed volume 
>   $$W_j(K) = V(\overset{n-j \text{ times}}{\overbrace{K,K, \ldots,K}}, \overset{j\text{ times}}{\overbrace{B,B,\ldots,B}})$$ 
>   is called the $j$-th quermassintegral of K.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gruber writes, in ch.6 of his *Convex and Discrete Geometry* (Springer, 2007):

> ... the general formulae of Kubota ... express the quermassintegrals $W_i(C)$ of $C$ as the mean of the $(d-i)$-dimensional volumes of the projections of $C$ onto $(d-i)$-dimensional linear subspaces.  These volumes are called Quermaße in German.

*Quer* means crosswise, or transverse; *maße* means mass.

Also, Schneider writes, in §4.2 of his *Convex Bodies: The Brunn–Minkowski Theory* (Cambridge UP, 1993):

> [The term *quermassintegrals*] comes from the German 'Quermaß', which can be the measure of either a cross-section or a projection.  The reason for this terminology will be clear when certain integral-geometric interpretations of the functions $W_i$ have been obtained in Section 4.5.

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely a German term. In general, *quer-* is used with the meaning *across*. My technical dictionary translates *Quermass* as *cross-sectional measure*, and *Quermassintegral* as *mean cross-sectional measure*. It also attributes the term to Minkowski.